# gcc *sometimes* resolves overload ambiguity in a strange way

Tags: c++, gcc

Before answering: This is not a question about how to get this code to do what I want. I already know how to do that (see the end of this question). This is a question about understanding why the compiler does what it does.

Please consider the following (simplified) code:

```
#include <iostream>

void operator>>( std::istream &stream, char chr )
{
    std::cout<<"Called "<<chr<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    char c='b';
    std::cin>>c;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc 4.8.2 with -Wall -Wextra produces one irrelevant warning (stream is unused). When run, however, prints "Called b".

I expected one of two things to happen. Either the program would read one character from the standard input, or the code would not compile because the compiler finds my operator and the operator defined by the standard library to be ambiguous. The operator defined by the standard library is, according to my understanding, equivalent to:

```
std::istream &operator>>( std::istream &stream, char &c )
```

Either way, I did not expect my operator to be called.

What's even stranger, the following code does not compile because of the ambiguity mentioned above:

```
#include <iostream>

void function(char &chr)
{
    std::cout<<"1 "<<chr<<"\n";
}

void function(char chr)
{
    std::cout<<"2 "<<chr<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    char c='a';
    function(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Aside from using functions rather than operators, I don't see any difference between the compiler's decision on both cases.

Note: I fully realize that what the standard library defines is not exactly the same as the prototype I wrote above. I would think that, when it comes to resolving functions, at least in this use case, there is no difference that matters. Bear in mind that the std definition cannot have default arguments, as this is an operator overload.

Also, as I wrote in the beginning of the question, I already know how to make the code do the right thing. Defining my operator with "const char &" instead of "char" causes the compiler to choose the correct overload.

Comment: Mmh, could it be related to the fact that your overload takes an `istream` which is more specific than a `stream`? I think I remember reading in the standard that when chosing between overloads in the set that the compiler built, the function with the most specific parameter types will actually be chosen. Wild guess as I'm not that sure...

Comment: Your input operator will cause [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), it should return the stream you pass in. And if you only get one warning, you really should enable more warnings (at least `-Wall`).

Comment: As for it being called, remember that C++ does overloading based on *arguments* and not return type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It has a return type of `void`

Comment: @gha.st Yes, and that's wrong. Actually, that should cause compiler errors if trying to chain multiple inputs in one expression.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But the OP *does not chain that operator*. Therefore no compiler errors, and no UB due to not returning anything from the function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is why I said the example is simplified. I actually considered putting that word in bold, but decided that the average StackOverflow user is intelligent enough to read what is clearly written. The same goes to the compilation flags used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the call `std::cin>>c;` there are two viable functions. The one you declared

```
void operator>>( std::istream &stream, char chr );
```

and the one defined in the streams library (as a specialization of a function template):

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& operator>>( basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& st, CharT& ch );
```

Selecting the best viable function that ultimately wins the overload resolution is done as described in `13.3.3 [over.match.best]`:

> 1 Deﬁne ICSi(F) as follows:
>
> > — if F is a static member function, ICS1
> >     (F) is deﬁned such that ICS1 (F) is neither better nor worse than ICS1
> >     (G) for any function G, and, symmetrically, ICS1 (G) is neither better
> >     nor worse than ICS1 (F); otherwise,
> >
> > — let ICSi(F) denote the
> >     implicit conversion sequence that converts the i-th argument in the
> >     list to the type of the i-th parameter of viable function F. 13.3.3.1
> >     deﬁnes the implicit conversion sequences and
> >     13.3.3.2 deﬁnes what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than
> >     another.
>
> Given these deﬁnitions, **a viable function F1 is deﬁned to be a better
>   function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i,
>   ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then**
>
> > — for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than
> >     ICSj(F2), or, if not that,
> >
> > — the context is an initialization by
> >     user-deﬁned conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the
> >     standard conversion sequence from the return type of F1 to the
> >     destination type (i.e., the type of the entity being initialized) is a
> >     better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from
> >     the return type of F2 to the destination type.
> >     [ Example: *omitted* ] or, if not that,
> >
> > — **F1 is a non-template function
> >     and F2 is a function template specialization**, or, if not that,
> >
> > — F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function
> >     template for F1 is more specialized than the template for F2 according
> >     to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.
>
> 2 If there is exactly one viable function that is a better function
>   than all other viable functions, then it is the one selected by
>   overload resolution; otherwise the call is ill-formed.

To simplify it - all else being equal, the non-template is a better match than a template specialization.

In the example with `function`, there is no such distinction between the candidates. Both implicit conversion sequences required for the call (`char`->`char&` and `char`->`char`) are Identity conversion and are ambiguous.

Comment: So, if I understand your answer correctly, the reason this does work with "const char &chr" is because "for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2)"?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh No, that's still ambigous. `char`->`const char&` is an Exact match.

Comment: If that were true, then overloading based on constantness of reference would never work.

Also, are you suggesting that gcc is wrong to compile that?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh There are additional rules that rank implicit conversion sequenced. For example from 13.3.3.2: `S1 is a better conversion sequence than S2 if [...] — S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same
type except for top-level cv-qualiﬁers, and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers
is more cv-qualiﬁed than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers.`

Comment: @ShacharShemesh I may have misunderstood. With `const char&`, did you mean you changed the signature of `function` or `operator>>`?

Comment: operator>>. With function it is obvious.

Comment: Well, the same quote from the comment above applies. Note that the ordering as defined in 13.3.3.2 is *partial*. Some pairs of sequences are ambiguous, some are not.

Comment: To repeat my first comment, then, if I understand your answer correctly, the reason this does work with "const char &chr" is because "for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2)"?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm sorry for the confusion. I thought we were talking about ranking char and const char&.

Answer (score 3):

The standard `operator >>` is a template. A non-template wins over a template (13.3.3/1) *provided the argument conversions are of equal quality* (13.3.3.2/3) (there are other conditions but they do not apply here).

Since neither of `char lvalue -> char` and `char lvalue -> char&` is better than the other, the non-template wins.

If you declare a non-templae with `const char&`, then it becomes worse than the standard `>>`, because `const char&` has more qualifiers than `char&`. So `std::operator>>` wins.

<s>There's another reason: Koenig lookup. The standard `operator>>` is a member of namespace std, it is only found if "normal" lookup fails. Koenig lookup would not be a factor if you have used `using namespace std`.</s> The preceding is incorrect.

Comment: Specifically, `operator>>` for character types are templates. Some others are not (but are member functions instead).

Comment: Its prototype is `template<class charT, class traits>
basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<charT,traits>&,
charT&);` to be exact.

Comment: A non-template doesn't always win over a template. If it did, then `void f(...) { } template <typename T> void f(T); int main() { f(3); }` would compile and run and do nothing. It does compile, but doesn't link, because it attempts to call `f<int>` which is not defined.

Comment: Your other reason is equally bogus. If it were right, then `namespace N { struct S { } s; void operator<<(S, int); } void operator<<(N::S, long) { } int main() { N::s << 3; }` would compile and run and do nothing. This too compiles, but doesn't link, because it finds `N::operator<<` even though there's also a `::operator<<` that *could* have been called instead.

Comment: @hvd: what was meant (and probably should be edited in to make clear) is that all other matching considerations the same, a non-template wins over a template.  in the `void f(...)` example, the match to an  `...` argument list is weaker than a match to `f<int>(int)` since the `int` argument list is an exact match.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That isn't what this answer says, and it is not at all clear to me from the answer that it's what n.m. meant, but yes, that sounds right.

Comment: -1 *The standard operator>> is a member of namespace std, it is only found if "normal" lookup fails.* That's totally incorrect.

Comment: Neither explanations explain why, when switching to "const char &chr", this suddenly works.

Comment: @n.m. It can only be called an "update" if it did not appear in the original question :-)