# Ambiguity in overloaded function: how is it resolved?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ambiguity

I have overloaded `<<` to print the contents of a `pair`, in two different forms (see code below). The first form is specific for the `pair` type defined. The second is `template`d, for any pair. Any of the two is ok for my pair type. When both prototypes precede the definition of `main`, the first one (specific) is used, regardless of the order of the prototypes. Only when the prototype for the first is commented, is the second used.

Why is the ambiguity resolved in this way, deciding which is the appropriate function to use?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<string, char> pair_t;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair_t& p);   // First form, specific

template<class first_class, class second_class>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<first_class, second_class>& p);   // Second form, generic

int main(void) {
        pair_t p2;
        p2 = make_pair("Fer", 'C');
        cout << p2 << endl;
        return 0;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair_t& p)
{
    os << p.first << " obtained \'" << p.second << "\'";
    return os;
}

template<class first_class, class second_class>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<first_class, second_class>& p)
{
    os << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) has an overloaded converting [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) which is:

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
constexpr pair( const pair<U1, U2>& p );
```

You did this:

```
p2 = make_pair("Fer", 'C');
```

the call `std::make_pair("Fer", 'C')` returns an object of type `std::pair<const char[4], char>` which is convertible to `std::pair<std::string, char>`.

Passing it to `std::cout`, will require overloaded resolution to instantiate the overloaded function templates creating a set of *function specialization*:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const std::pair<std::string, char>& p)
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const std::pair<std::string, char>& p);    //compiler generated template specialization
```

The rules for which one may be selected is captured [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function)

> For each pair of viable function F1 and F2, the implicit conversion
>   sequences from the i-th parameter to i-th argument are ranked to
>   determine which one is better (except the first argument, the implicit
>   object argument for static member functions has no effect on the
>   ranking)
>
> *F1* is determined to be a better function than *F2* if implicit conversions for all arguments of *F1* are not worse than the implicit
>   conversions for all arguments of *F2*, **and**
>
> 1. there is at least one argument of *F1* whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of
>      *F2*
> 2. or. if not that, (only in context of non-class initialization by conversion), the standard conversion sequence from the return type of
>      *F1* to the type being initialized is better than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of *F2*
> 3. **or, if not that, *F1* is a non-template function while *F2* is a template specialization**
> 4. or, if not that, *F1* and *F2* are both template specializations and *F1* is more specialized according to the partial ordering rules
>      for template specializations

Comment: Seems to hit the nail in the head. With this pointer I could read a little more. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23424604/2707864) provides a similar answer, plus it gives the original source in the standard.